# Qt vs Embarcadero RAD Studio for web application development

Tags: qt, c++builder

I am a Embarcadero RAD Studio user. Mainly C++Builder. I have been using this product for more than 20 years.

But I am tired of all the unresolved bugs. I am stuck with bugs I am sure they will never fix unless I pay to upgrade to their new product as usual.

I recently saw some Qt code. And noticed that objects like `QString`, `QVariant`, `QRectF`, etc... are really more powerful compare to RAD Studio's equivalent objects.

Unfortunately, I don't have an available computer to install a trial version and test to see the differences.

I would appreciate if there are some users who have used the 2 development tools and can tell me if Qt really is better?

Does it have less bugs? Better support?

Is it a RAD environment?

Is it easy to build web server applications, like Intraweb applications?

Does it have its own database, like Interbase? If yes, is it possible to find tools to migrate an Interbase database to a Qt database?

Comment: Who closed this question on the argument that it is opinion-based? We don't have the right to ask other users about their experiences?

Comment: You could try posting this question at https://en.delphipraxis.net/forum/41-general-help/

Comment: Policing is all over the place here. Officially SO is about code, yet I see plenty of posts without code or dealing about applications. On the other hand valid programming questions like this one are almost always closed, which is a shame.
V10.4.2. finally fixed all my major bugs (after almost 10 year wait) so you should definitely try that. A few years ago I tried Qt and could easily find bugs, so was rather underwhelmed. I'm glad I did not make the switch.